# Elasticsearch updating ignore_above giving illegal_argument_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to update the value of `ignore_above` in my indices. I'm using PUT to `/_mappings/my_type` (tester) with a body like so:

```
{
 "properties": {
  "message.keyword": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "ignore_above": 20 
  }
 }
}
```

It returns: `"illegal_argument_exception"`, `"reason": "mapper [message] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"`

Any ideas on how to solve this would be excellent.

Here is my mapping:

```
"mappings": {
        "tester": {
            "properties": {
                "message": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Can you show the current mapping please?

Comment: Added the mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it looks like 'message' field is of 'text' data type, meaning analysed text, and not a Json object/map.

When you try to set mapping for 'message.keyword' you are referring to message as an object, and that's the issue.

you need to change 'message' to a [multi field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) in order to have both keyword and text versions of it.

Comment: I don't completely follow, I believe I have this already as I have "message" which is type text and the field "keyword", which is type keyword and contains the ignore above. Do I need another field?

Comment: the mapping should contain both the higher level 'message' definition and the nested 'message.keyword' inside, like in the multi-field link example I pasted, something like: {
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type":  "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Yes I think it already does, I added my mapping above. Please take a look and tell me what you think

Comment: If you follow @ziv's comment, you'll be able to change the `ignore_above` property as you expect.

Comment: the issue is due to the fact you used "message.keyword" and it is treated differently then the nested version. your PUT request should work in this format: {
  "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type":  "keyword",
              "ignore_above":202
            }
          }
        }
      }
   
}